# Should I refer std::vector size when the number is explicitly given

Tags: c++, performance, vector, stl, containers

I'm coding a simple function using std::vector below where input is an integer vector and the function proceeds the iteration based on the number of elements in the vector.

In terms of space and time efficiency, which following code are suitable?
HugeClass is actually a Big Integer which contains complex arithmetic while I put a simple arithmetic below for simplicity.

1) Gives a dimension of vector

```
void (HugeClass& huge, std::vector<int>& vec, int dim){
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++){
        huge+=vec[i];
    }
}
```

2) Calls a std::vector.size() to iterate

```
void (HugeClass& huge, std::vector<int>& vec){
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
        huge+=vec[i];
    }
}
```

dim can range in [100,1000000]

Comment: people have twisted way of thinking what makes C++ programs fast..

Comment: You can do `for(int i=0, ie=vec.size();i<ie;i++)`, but  `for(int i : vec) {huge+=i}` is the more modern way to write that.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of a for loop in C++ is:

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
   statement(s);
}
```

Here is the flow of control in a for loop:

1. The init step is executed first, and only once. This step allows you to declare and initialize any loop control variables. You are not required to put a statement here, as long as a semicolon appears.
2. Next, the condition is evaluated. If it is true, the body of the loop is executed. If it is false, the body of the loop does not execute and flow of control jumps to the next statement just after the for loop.
3. After the body of the for loop executes, the flow of control jumps back up to the increment statement. This statement allows you to update any loop control variables. This statement can be left blank, as long as a semicolon appears after the condition.

So in the case of

```
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) {
        huge+=vec[i];
}
```

vec.size() called each time but is probably inlined, and is probably a simple function.

On top of which

A smart enough optimizer may be able to deduce that it is a loop invariant with no side effects and elide it entirely (this is easier if the code is inlined, but may be possible even if it is not if the compiler does global optimization)